# I have problem with Pillow: "no suitable image found"

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, python-imaging-library

I tried to make a paint clone using python Pillow Image ImageDraw.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

But every time, when I run a program it gives me this error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mralbert/Desktop/PAINT_KURWA/PAINT.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 84, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-312-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libXau.6.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libxcb.1.1.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXau.6.0.0.dylib: cannot load 'libXau.6.0.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXau.6.0.0.dylib: cannot load 'libXau.6.0.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
```

I tried to solve this problem by myself, but nothing works. I use macOs High Sierra 10.13.6, Python 3.12.1.

Comment: How did you install Pillow? You seem to have some X11 references in there which seem unlikely to be correct on macOS.

Comment: I use pip3 install Pillow, but I also tried to install different versions of pillow, howerer, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The docs provides some warnings which appears to be relevant to your error message:

1. Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.
2. Pillow >= 1.0 no longer supports import Image. Please use from PIL import Image instead.
3. **Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports import _imaging. Please use from PIL.Image import core as _imaging instead.**

As a last resort, you may want to uninstall and reinstall this package. See [the docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: I have no installed PIL, only Pillow. I use from PIL import Image. What i do wrong?